# Complex php mysqli query to insert data if not exist: getting Duplicate column name '?'

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So guys, please review this sample code of me, and help me , i cannot find the solution , keep getting Duplicate column name on the line where I passed parameters like ?,?,?,? . 
I passed 7 variables all together in the query.  Any idea what can be the problem?

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO wifi (ssid, password, name, surname) SELECT *        
FROM(SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?) AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
ssid,name,surname FROM wifi WHERE ssid=? AND name=? AND 
surname=?) LIMIT 1;";


if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($SQL)) {
$stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $ssid, $password, $name, $surname,$ssid, $name, $surname);
$stmt->execute();
echo $SQL;
}

if ( false===$stmt ) {

   die('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));
 }
```

OK, I know it is little complicated, but this query is working on mysql server. I just have problem doing it through PHP, as it returns **prepare() failed: Duplicate column name '?'**

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you add a unique index on `(ssid, name, surname)`. Then you can use `INSERT IGNORE`, and it will automatically skip if they already have a row.

Comment: It looks like `prepare()` doesn't realize that you can use expressions in the `SELECT` list, so it thinks those are column names rather than placeholders.

Comment: I am not sure how to accomplish, i am not so experienced, but i would like to get to know what's the problem with this..  I dont know why prepare() is not recognizing ? marks, i did it like in other tutorials..

Comment: Like I said, it looks like a limitation in `prepare()`, it doesn't allow you to substitute placeholders at that part of the query.

Comment: Placeholders are only allowed where expressions are allowed, not where SQL requires table or column names. It looks like it's confused about the `SELECT` list.

Comment: Hm, yea Barmar that can be the problem, if someone knows workaround to this please let me know..

Comment: If you can provide me with instructions on how to add unique index, I could make this solved

Comment: `FROM(  SELECT ? AS \`ssid\`, ? AS \`password\`, ? AS \`name\`, ? AS \`surname\`) AS tmp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO wifi (ssid, password, name, surname) 
        SELECT ?, ?, ?, ? FROM DUAL 
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM wifi 
            WHERE ssid=? AND name=? AND surname=?)";
```

`DUAL` is a dummy table name that you can use when you don't need to access an actual table. Putting the placeholders in the main `SELECT` rather than a subquery seems to avoid the placeholder problem.

The other way you can do this is by creating a unique index on those columns:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ssid_name_surname ON wifi (ssid, name, surname);
```

Then you can use:

```
$SQL = "INSERT IGNORE INTO wifi (ssid, password, name, surname)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

If you want to update the password if it already exists, use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` instead of `INSERT IGNORE`:

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO wifi (ssid, password, name, surname)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE password = VALUES(password)";
```

Comment: Yes man thank you! I did with CREATE UNIQUE INDEX as you proposed, and it's working! Thank you very much man!

Comment: Hey i have one more problem, I would like not to replace the item in database if same ssid, name and surname is found, but if different password is passed with existing ssid,name and surname, i would like to replace password inside existing row! Is that too much complicated?

Comment: That's great, thanks! Only should be written ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE password = "some_value" , instead of VALUES() part..

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE wifi ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx (ssid,name,surname);

INSERT IGNORE INTO wifi (ssid, password, name, surname) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: He's getting the error when he calls `prepare()`, not `bind_param()`

Comment: not working, i get the same prepare() failed: Duplicate column name '?'

Comment: I do not use INSERT IGNORE as i don't know how to reorganize the table in mysql server.. do i have to ALTER the columns in some way? but let me try